# Clone object and save in a different table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a number of tables with a large number of rows, some of them nearing a million. There are background tasks which keep accessing some recent records in these tables. Because of the ever increasing size, the tasks keep on taking a longer time to complete. Besides, when showing data on the front end, the calls to server also take a very long time.

Hence, I thought it is better to create a replica of such tables (as an archive) and keep saving data in these 'archive' tables (for future use if any). The idea is that whenever a record is completely processed, it will be deleted from the 'live' tables and be stored in the 'archive' tables.

PHP clone does not work as it creates an entity exactly same as the orginal. 
One definite way is to follow exact same steps to create the entity, and always simultaneously keep on modifying.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should analyze your database queries (EXPLAIN if you are using mysql) to see if you are using indices correctly; the number of records is not that exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "Partitioning". Both MySQL and Postgres have some beefy manuals.

Probably the best way to implement this is to use a daemon script that runs the partitioning queries every X time.